# Eliminar divs dentro de otro div

Tags: html, jquery, css, selectores, selectores-css

Tengo el siguiente codigo HTML:

```
<div id="principal" class="simple-modal-content simple-modal-audit-content modal-content rounded-modal simplemodal-data" style="padding: 10px; display: block;" id="simplemodal-data">
        <div id="auditoriaCabecera">
            <p class="titulares font26" style="color: #3270a3; font-weight: 300;">Auditoria</p>
            <div style="float:right; cursor:pointer;"><a class="modal-close"><i class="fa fa-close azul_aca font18"></i> </a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="celeste_Collapse">  
        </div>  
        <div class="celeste_Collapse">  
        </div>  
        <div class="celeste_Collapse">  
        </div>  
        <div class="celeste_Collapse">  
        </div>  
        <div class="celeste_Collapse">  
        </div>                        
</div>
```

Lo que necesite es eliminar (limpiar) los divs hijos de id="principal" excepto el primero. He utilizado algunos selectores como `.first()` pero no he podido solucionarlo.

Gracias!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Puedes resolverlo con una combinación de las pseudo-clases **CSS** `:not` y `:first-child`.

```js
$('#principal > div:not(:first-child)').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="principal" class="simple-modal-content simple-modal-audit-content modal-content rounded-modal simplemodal-data" style="padding: 10px; display: block;" id="simplemodal-data">
  <div id="auditoriaCabecera">
    <p class="titulares font26" style="color: #3270a3; font-weight: 300;">Auditoria</p>
    <div style="float:right; cursor:pointer;">
      <a class="modal-close"><i class="fa fa-close azul_aca font18"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="celeste_Collapse">
    Este div se borrará
  </div>  
  <div class="celeste_Collapse">  
    Este div se borrará
  </div>  
  <div class="celeste_Collapse">  
    Este div se borrará
  </div>  
  <div class="celeste_Collapse">
    Este div se borrará
  </div>  
  <div class="celeste_Collapse">
    Este div se borrará
  </div>                        
</div>
```

**Referencia:** [Pseudo-clases CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes)

Comment: Esto funciona aunque se tenga varios divs antes y después del div que se selecciona y se lo pone en el script? pregunto xq estoy editando en atom y no funciona aunque le ponga en un documento externo.

Answer (score 8):

Yo he hecho una solución con javaScript espero que te sirva.

```
<script>
    var padre =document.getElementById("principal")
    var hijos = padre.children
    var nHijos = hijos.length // Hay que declarar antes la longitud porque esto ira cambiando
    for (var i=1;i<nHijos;i++){
        hijos[1].remove() // Siempre eliminamos el hijo de la posicion 1 porque se iran cambiando de posicion cada vez que eliminamos uno
    }
    console.log(padre.children)

</script>
```

El codigo se puede acortar a esto pero es menos entendible:

```
<script>
    var nHijos =document.getElementById("principal").children.length
    for (var i=1;i<nHijos;i++){
        document.getElementById("principal").children[1].remove()
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

## Sin JQuery

Si no necesitas JQuery en tu proyecto puedes usar [Element.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) que viene en todos los navegadores

```js
// borramos los div's a partir del segundo elemento
// Tambien es posible usar '.celeste_Collapse'
document.querySelectorAll('#principal > div:nth-child(n+2)').forEach(e => e.remove())
```

```html
<div id="principal"
    class="simple-modal-content simple-modal-audit-content modal-content rounded-modal simplemodal-data"
    style="padding: 10px; display: block;" id="simplemodal-data">
    <div id="auditoriaCabecera">
        <p class="titulares font26" style="color: #3270a3; font-weight: 300;">Auditoria</p>
        <div style="float:right; cursor:pointer;">
            <a class="modal-close"><i class="fa fa-close azul_aca font18"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="celeste_Collapse">
        Este div se borrará
    </div>
    <div class="celeste_Collapse">
        Este div se borrará
    </div>
    <div class="celeste_Collapse">
        Este div se borrará
    </div>
    <div class="celeste_Collapse">
        Este div se borrará
    </div>
    <div class="celeste_Collapse">
        Este div se borrará
    </div>
</div>
```